# Require subclasses to set a parent class's data member

Tags: java

This seems like a common task but I got a little confused. Suppose I have an abstract parent class with a data member and corresponding getter/setter.

```
public abstract class Parent {

    private MyObj myObj;

    public MyObj getMyObj() { return myObj; }
    public void setMyObj(MyObj myObj) { this.myObj = myObj; }
}
```

I need to force the child classes to set the "myObj" variable. I have 2 options:

1. Make the setter "abstract" (but not the getter). This seems weird to
   me, I haven't seen it before.
2. Avoid declaring the data member in
   parent at all. Just have one parent method,

   abstract public MyObj getMyObj();

and then the parent will always refer as getMyObj().getField1(), getMyObj().getField2(), etc. Each time a new object is created, rather than storing it in a single place.

What's the standard way to force a child class to  set a parent class's data variable? Is it a new abstract method, outside the getters/setters?

Comment: Why do you even need to do this? Why not just reuse the same data member, getter and setter?

Comment: @Mureinik: The reason is, although you can just call setMyObj() from the child class, you're not required to do this. But the child must set it.

Comment: If the value is required, require it in the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have the compiler enforce that `myObj` is set, you can do this:

```
public abstract class Parent {

    private final MyObj myObj;
```

The `final` means the value cannot be changed, but also that it must be set. Since you have a setter, the value may be updated; if that's expected don't add the `final` keyword.

To make sure the field is set, add a constructor:

```
    protected Parent( MyObj initial ) {
        if ( initial == null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Must provide a value!" );
        this.myObj = initial;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the setter method from your child object.

Comment: I can call the setter method, but I'm not *required* to do it. But the child must be required to set it in the parent.